# Powershell CSV with headers to hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with a header row and I want to convert it to a Hashtable.

For example, this is my input:

```
#Version1.0
#Fields:ID,Data
1,data1
2,data2
3,data3
```

I want the output to be a hashtable where Key=ID and Value =Data.

This is what I have, but the results aren't quite what I want.

```
$mytable = Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Header ID,Data
$HashTable=@{}
foreach($r in $mytable)
{
    $HashTable[$r.ID]=$r.Data
}
```

This creates my table, but when I output it later via 
    $str = $Hashtable | Out-String
    Write-Host $str

I'm getting the following:

```
Name                  Value
--------              -----------
#Fields:ID            Data
1                     data1
2                     data2
3                     data3
```

How do I get rid of the Headers being written to my hashtable? Is there a more elegant solution than sticking if ($r.ID.StartsWith("#")) { continue; }?

Thanks!
-C

Answer (score 11):

The default behavior in Import-Csv is to use the first (un-commented) line as the headers. Instead of defining the header in the command, remove "#Fields:" from the header line.

```
#Version1.0
ID,Data
1,data1
2,data2
3,data3
```

Then you can create the hashtable like this:

```
$mytable = Import-Csv -Path $filePath
$HashTable=@{}
foreach($r in $mytable)
{
    $HashTable[$r.ID]=$r.Data
}
```

Which returns:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              data2
1                              data1
3                              data3
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$HashTable = @{}
Import-Csv $filePath | % { $HashTable[$_.ID] = $_.Data }
```

Comment: For the low cost of knowing the headers in the CSV file, this snippet does exactly what I need it to do!

Answer (score 3):

Following down @llamb's road of using the first data line as headers, I had luck with:

```
PS> $mytable = Import-CSV -Path $filePath | Group-Object -AsHashTable -Property "ID"

PS> $mytable["2"]

ID Data
-- ----
2  data2

PS> $mytable["2"].Data
data2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
Get-Content $filePath | where {$_ -notmatch '^#'} | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ID,Data
```

It remove all the lines begining with # before readingg then as CSV lines.

Comment: I considered that, but it's not going to get you a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

just specify a delimiter.
in your case:

> $mytable = Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Delimiter ","

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's "more elegant", but:

```
$mytable = Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Header ID,Data
$HashTable=@{}
foreach($r in $mytable)
{
    if ($r.ID -notlike '#*')
     {$HashTable[$r.ID]=$r.Data}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the 2nd line as your header:

`ipcsv .\test.csv | % { $o = @{}} { $o[$_."#Fields:ID"] = $_.Data } {$o}`